# how to search multiple documents by giving multiple id's at the sametime in express and mongo db using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

this is my route handler

```
router.get("/get-bookmarks", async (req, res) => {
  const bookmarks = await Post.find({ _id: { $all: req.body.idList } });
  if (!bookmarks) return res.status(404).send("No bookmarks yet");
  return res.send(bookmarks);
});
```

this is the data to search using postman

```
{
"idList": ["60c07302f033f51f6c87c986","60c07399f033f51f6c87c989","60c0736ff033f51f6c87c988"]
}
```

Comment: try replacing `$all` with `$in`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `$in` operator, like this:

```
Post.find({ _id: { $in: req.body.idList } });
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gs-nuaB-_Ux